# What, if anything, are the consequences of temporarily enabling and then disabling WebRTC in Firefox?

Tags: web-browser, firefox, configuration, webrtc, conference

For security and privacy purposes, it's best to keep WebRTC disabled if you aren't using it.  Firefox makes this easy by simply setting `media.peerconnection.enabled` to `false`.

Due to COVID-19, the use of teleconferencing has increased dramatically, which often requires WebRTC.  If WebRTC has always been disabled in Firefox, and someone enables it temporarily, are there any consequences besides simply the toggling of `media.peerconnection.enabled`?

I'm thinking of additional Firefox settings getting automatically changed, settings outside of Firefox (e.g. Windows) changing, Firefox profile files being created/modified, Windows registry entries being changed, et al.

Although I am interested in learning about *any* consequences, those focused on security and privacy are of greater importance.

I searched the web, and I didn't find any details.  Before I spend an hour or two creating system images and comparing them, I figured it a good idea to ask here.